# Collision between moving circular discs

Tags: geometry

I am trying to figure out how to detect collision between two moving circular discs that move along a pretedermined path with a known speed.

Example:

[image]

Circular disk $A$ with radius $r1$ moves along the path $AB$ with speed $U_a$.

Circular disk $C$ with radius $r2$  moves along the path $CDEF$ with speed $U_c$.

How can I detect if the circular disks will collide?

### EDIT

I think I need to simplify the path of the second disk and calculate the distance of $g$ as shown in the gif below.

[image]

Comment: that is the only obvious thing

Comment: Break up the problem into intervals where both disks have uniform motion.

Comment: it's not that simple, I have already tried solving it with no success. The complex path of the second disk makes it harder, although I could just split the path and solve the same problem 3 times.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  When both disks are in uniform motion, you can treat one center as if it were fixed at the origin and determine whether the closest approach of the other center is in that interval of time.

Comment: it is harder than it seems, right now I am trying to figure out the equation of the AC based on the speed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simplify to just two disks each moving along a straight segment,
at perhaps different speeds. And then repeat over the multiple segments.

Without loss of generality, you may assume that the segment from $a$ to $b$,
$\|ab\|=1$,
is traversed at unit speed with $t \in [0,1]$, while the second segment
from $c$ to $d$ is traversed quicker, at speed $s>1$.
$$p_1 = a + t (b-a)$$
$$p_2 = c + t s (d-c)$$
Now compute $\|p_1-p_2\|$ and see when its square is $\le (r_1 + r_2)^2$.
This is a quadratic equation in $t$ until $p_2$ reaches $d$;
then it is a different quadratic equation while $p_2$ remains at $d$ while
$p_1$ is still moving.

Your nice animation illustrates it perfectly.

Comment: although I dont understand why you make the assumption that ∥ab∥=1, I manged to solve it using a similar method.

Comment: I assumed $|ab|=1$ to make it (slightly) simpler. Scaling by $1/|ab|$ allows that.